# 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable error

Tags: pandas

Hi I am getting the following error

'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable

when performing the calculation in the following manner

```
rolling_means = pd.rolling_mean(prices,20,min_periods=20)`
rolling_std =  pd.rolling_std(prices, 20)`

#print rolling_means.head(20)
 upper_band = rolling_means + (rolling_std)* 2
 lower_band = rolling_means - (rolling_std)* 2
```

I am not sure how to resolve, can someone point me in right direction....

Answer (score 18):

The error `TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable` means that you tried to call a numpy array as a function. We can reproduce the error like so in the repl:

```
In [16]: import numpy as np

In [17]: np.array([1,2,3])()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/user/<ipython-input-17-1abf8f3c8162> in <module>()
----> 1 np.array([1,2,3])()

TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable
```

If we are to assume that the error is indeed coming from the snippet of code that you posted (something that you should check,) then you must have reassigned either `pd.rolling_mean` or `pd.rolling_std` to a numpy array earlier in your code.

What I mean is something like this:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: import pandas as pd

In [3]: pd.rolling_mean(np.array([1,2,3]), 20, min_periods=5) # Works
Out[3]: array([ nan,  nan,  nan])

In [4]: pd.rolling_mean = np.array([1,2,3])

In [5]: pd.rolling_mean(np.array([1,2,3]), 20, min_periods=5) # Doesn't work anymore...
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/user/<ipython-input-5-f528129299b9> in <module>()
----> 1 pd.rolling_mean(np.array([1,2,3]), 20, min_periods=5) # Doesn't work anymore...

TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable
```

So, basically you need to search the rest of your codebase for `pd.rolling_mean = ...` and/or `pd.rolling_std = ...` to see where you may have overwritten them.

---

Also, if you'd like, you can put in [`reload(pd)`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=reload#reload) just before your snippet, which should make it run by restoring the value of `pd` to what you originally imported it as, but I still **highly** recommend that you try to find where you may have reassigned the given functions.

Answer (score 0):

For everyone with this problem in 2021, sometimes you can have this problem when you create
a numpy variable with the same name as one of your function, what happens is that instead of calling the function python tries to call the numpy array as a function and you get the error, just change the name of the numpy variable

Answer (score 0):

I met the same question and the solved.

The point is that my **function parameters and variables have the same name.**
Try to give them different name.