# How do I solve this broyden1 np.ndarray calling problem?

Tags: python, numpy

first time poster here, currently working on a project for uni and I'm a little stuck.

This part of the task is to use the Monte Carlo method to estimate the value of an integral (in this case, the function we are integrating is f(r). Here's my current code:

```
import numpy as np # import numpy
from scipy.optimize #import broyden1

def U(r, ep, sig):
    return 4*ep*((sig/r)**(12)-(sig/r)**(6)) # return U(r) 

# Function to calculate f(r)
def f(r, ep, sig):
    Ur = 4*ep*((sig/r)**(12)-(sig/r)**(6)) # puts U(r) into this function
    return (1-np.exp(-Ur/(k*T)))*(r**2) # return f(r)

data = np.array([[2.56,3.75,3.4,4.07],[1.41,1.32,1.66,3.04]]) #He, N2, Ar, Xe
k =  1.38*10**-23 # Boltzmann constant
T = 300 # temperature value T
R = np.linspace(1*10**-10, 10, 1000) # r defined with 1000 values between 2.5 and 10
U = U(R, data[1,0], data[0,0])# calculate U((r)
F = f(R, data[1,0], data[0,0]) # calculate f(r)

cutoff = broyden1(F,6)
```

I get an error message 'TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable'. I know this is a very common error message but I can't figure out from other posts on here what my problem is.

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['numpy.ndarray' object is not callable error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19348851/numpy-ndarray-object-is-not-callable-error)

Comment: Based off this, I removed `U = U(R, data[1,0], data[0,0])` and `F = f(R, data[1,0], data[0,0])` and tried calling the original function (`cutoff = broyden1(f,6)`) and am now getting 'TypeError: f() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'ep' and 'sig''. I'm not sure if this is because I took the advice from your link wrong or not though

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mixing Joules with eV.

This part in your force function is blowing up

`np.exp(-Ur/(k*T))`

Your script is not reaching the last function call (i.e., `cutoff = broyden1(F,6)`)

I think because your Boltzmann constants should be expressed in eVK-1 rather than JK-1. So `k = 8.617333262145*10**-5`

**EDIT**

Possibly your problem is related to this [issue](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/3562). I did some modifications to your code and now is running. However it's taking time to find a solution.

```
from functools import partial
import numpy as np # import numpy
from scipy.optimize import broyden1

def U(r, ep, sig):
    return 4*ep*((sig/r)**(12)-(sig/r)**(6)) # return U(r) 

# Function to calculate f(r)
def F(r):
    ep = 1.41
    sig = 2.56
    Ur = 4*ep*((sig/r)**(12)-(sig/r)**(6)) # puts U(r) into this function
    return (1-np.exp(-Ur/(k*T)))*(r**2) # return f(r)

data = np.array([[2.56,3.75,3.4,4.07],[1.41,1.32,1.66,3.04]]) #He, N2, Ar, Xe
#k =  1.38*10**-23 # Boltzmann constant
k = 8.617333262145*10**-5
T = 300 # temperature value T
R = np.linspace(1*10**-10, 10, 1000) # r defined with 1000 values between 2.5 and 10
U = U(R, data[1,0], data[0,0])# calculate U((r)
#F = f(R, data[1,0], data[0,0])# calculate f(r)
cutoff = broyden1(F,R,f_tol=1e-2)
```

Comment: I tried putting that in but I still get the same error message. I have the f(r) function in another code and it seems to run okay there. 

Thanks for replying!